# Python regex to find string on HTML and write to text file

Tags: python, regex, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to find 4 lines of strings on a parsed html Youtube link and write them into a text file.

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?something'
r = requests.get(url)
r.text
```

I already got the regex of 3 of the string lines but I can't seem to solve the #3. And how to get only the first one in #4?

Also, I thought I know how to do Regex in Python but I can't figure it out. How to do it in PYTHON?

- Here are the types of strings I need to look for:

1. 

"ownerChannelName":"(Regex alphanumeric including spaces)","uploadDate"

***between the "ownerChannelName":" and ","uploadDate" is the reGex without the parenthesis.

Solution:

```
"ownerChannelName":"[a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]*","uploadDate"
```

2. 

subscribed":true},"navigationEndpoint":{

solution: exactly the same - no regex

3.

```
<script >
ytcfg.set({"INNERTUBE_CONTEXT":{"client


</script>
```

*** i need everything between the script tags

Here is what I got so far...

```
ytcfg.set({"INNERTUBE_CONTEXT":{"client":{[a-zA-Z0-9:"\.%{},/()_-]*"}}});
```

But it doesn't work. Is it even possible to get everything between these things:

`ytcfg.set({"INNERTUBE_CONTEXT":{"client":{`       and

`"}}});`

4.
videoplayback?expire=10integers\u0026ei=22 alphanumeric characters\u0026ip=xx.xx.xx.xx\

solution:

```
videoplayback\?expire=\d{10}\\\\u0026ei=[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{22}\\\\u0026ip=\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b\\\\
```

--- but how will i get only the first one on the page?

---

Lastly, can I put everything in a function(with write to text file) and apply to each of the url get by chromedriver?

```
with open("url.txt") as f:
    
        for line in f:
                if line.rstrip():
                        url = line.strip()
                        print(url)
                        driver.get(url)
                        time.sleep(random.randint(180, 350))
                        ***Do the Function here***
```

Please, how does the function should look like. Sorry, my head is killing me already. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `re.search` it return first match only

```py
import re

regex = r"videoplayback\?expire=\d{10}\\u0026ei=[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{22}\\u0026ip=\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b\\"

test_str = ("videoplayback?expire=0123456789\\u0026ei=0123456789abcdefghin22\\u0026ip=10.1.1.1\\\n"
    "  videoplayback?expire=0123456789\\u0026ei=0123456789abcdefghin22\\u0026ip=10.1.1.2\\\n"
    "   videoplayback?expire=0123456789\\u0026ei=0123456789abcdefghin22\\u0026ip=10.1.1.3\\\n"
    "    videoplayback?expire=0123456789\\u0026ei=0123456789abcdefghin22\\u0026ip=10.1.1.4\\\n"
    "     videoplayback?expire=0123456789\\u0026ei=0123456789abcdefghin22\\u0026ip=10.1.1.5\\")

matches = re.search(regex, test_str)
if matches:
    print(matches.group())
```

Comment: Hi @정도유. 

Thank you for your answer. Do I need to manually enter the `test_str` into the code? if so, i don't like the option. :)

Comment: For your case, `test_str` can be replaced with `r.text`

Comment: Hi @정도유.


I tried it like this:

`import re`
`import requests`

`url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1DCQd74oL4A'`
`r = requests.get(url)`
`r.text`


`regex = r"videoplayback\?expire=\d{10}\\u0026ei=[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{22}\\u0026ip=\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b\\"`

`test_str = r.text`


`matches = re.search(regex, test_str)`
`if matches:`
   ` print(matches.group())`


But it's blank

Comment: Sorry @정도유, I thought I know how to do this in Python but not really. I should have asked properly. I have edited my question.

Comment: Could you give me a sample string?